# Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]

Tags: tomcat

I get the following error when I try to initiate Tomcat connector on port 443.
I'm using windows server,

**SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]**
**org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed**
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:935)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:530)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:852)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:656)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
**Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind**
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:227)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:202)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1043)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:540)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:932)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM\_Bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260314/java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind)

Comment: Hello ,  I suggest to you use code block for understandable questions